# How to disable imageview events?

Tags: java, android, events, imageview

I'm trying to implement custom seek bar, but with icons on sides, so I put SeekBar and two image views on sides with low volume icon and high volume icon (on screenshot)

so everything is cool until I move slider to be behind of the volume icon, in this situation imageview catches all touch event and user not able to change volume, because they don't send to SeekBar, is there a way to disable imageviews events? any workaround?

[image]

```
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always delegate this event from ImageView to your SeekBar by typing this:

```
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mSeekBar.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yea, I tried already this, but it works pretty laggy, if I click on right button the slider goes to minumum value suddenly, and there is still a feel like image is catching events on touch

Comment: Image is definitely catching event. This way you are just delegating the event to the SeekBar. Clicking the image makes the click on the SeekBar.
Do you want to be able to move seekBar on touch or just by clicking on the images on the sides?

Comment: hi, thanks for response, yea I want to move seekBar on touch, but when I click on right sided volume image it goes to zero suddenly, but I've expected smooth behaviour, so volume indicator will be under this icon at least

Comment: well, I guess it's because I'm not overriding ontouch event, can't you say me how to do this in right way?